# Как сделать чтобы при клике на иконку можно было перейти на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header-list
 display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 justify-content: center
 padding-left: 0
 list-style-type: none
 margin: 0
 &__item
  margin-left: 30px
  position: relative
  &:hover
   i
    opacity: 0
   img
    opacity: 1
  &:first-child
   margin-left: 0
  a
   color: #333
   z-index: 2
  i
   font-size: 40px
   opacity: 1
   transform: 0.5s
  img
   position: absolute
   top: 0
   opacity: 0
   transition: 0.5s
   z-index: 1
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
    <ul class="header-list">
     <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://ru-ru.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />

     </li>
     <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://telegram.org/"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a>
      <img src="img/telegram.svg" alt="">
     </li>
     <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://vk.com/"><i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a>
      <img src="img/vk.svg" alt="">
     </li>
     <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=ru"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <img src="img/instagram.svg" alt="">
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Dantessss не при наведении, а при клике

Comment: Dantessss понял свой косяк, заголовок уже изменил

Comment: Почему бы не использовать тег `<a>`???

Comment: Dantessss img не дает перейти

Comment: Так `<img>` и не обернут в тег `<a>`. Вот как должно быть https://jsfiddle.net/ge052s1y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://ru-ru.facebook.com/">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://telegram.org/">
        <i class="fab fa-telegram"></i>
        <img src="img/telegram.svg" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://vk.com/">
        <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
        <img src="img/vk.svg" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=ru">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        <img src="img/instagram.svg" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: да я понял, что меня перемкнуло не слабо